# Tooltips do not seem to work with InfiniteLine (ConicHullRegion) in 2D Graphics

Tags: graphics, tooltip

Fixed in **10.1**

---

The `InfiniteLine` functionality added to version 10 is very handy for obvious reasons, however a `Tooltip` added to them in `Graphics` does not display.

For example, evaluating:

```
Graphics[{Red, Tooltip[Circle[], "Circle"], Green, 
  Tooltip[InfiniteLine[{{-1, -1}, {1, 1}}], "InfiniteLine"], Blue, 
  Tooltip[Line[{{-1, 1}, {1, -1}}], "Line"]}]
```

And moving the mouse cursor over the green line does not display a tooltip.

- Is this specific to my set-up Mac OS X (10.9.4) and *Mathematica* 10.0.1?
- Is there a workaround (aside from "manually" calculating the line over the plot range)?

---

NB: This does seem to work in 3D

```
Graphics3D[{Red, Tooltip[Sphere[], "Sphere"], Green, 
  Tooltip[InfiniteLine[{{-1, -1, -1}, {1, 1, 1}}], "InfiniteLine"], 
  Blue, Tooltip[Line[{{-1, 1, 1}, {1, -1, -1}}], "Line"]}]
```

### Edit

As @Kuba points out in the comments in general tooltips are not displayed for 2D `ConicHullRegion`s of which `InfiniteLine` is a special case.

Comment: Just to confirm, I encounter the same issue with the example code. I'm on Mathematica 10 on Mac OS X 10.10.

Comment: The same in *Mathematica* 10.0.1 under Win7 x64.

Comment: It is `ConicHullRegion` and it seems that `Tooltip` does not work with it at all.

Comment: I have reported this to Wolfram support.

Comment: Not fixed in 10.0.2.